# Issue in processing/selecting decimal datatype data using pandasql from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

I have a parquet file with 4 columns. It looks something like below.

```
    +----+-----------+-------+--------+
    |TYPE|         ID|   SRNO|     AMT|
    +--- +-----------+-------+--------+
    |D   |     123456|      1|  100.00|
    |D   |     123457|      2|  200.00|
    |D   |     123459|      3|  500.00|
    |D   |     123458|      4| 1000.00|
    +----+-----------+-------+--------+
```

The Schema for this file is

```
    dataframe.printSchema

    root
     |-- TYPE: string (nullable = true)
     |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- SRNO: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- AMT: decimal(15,2) (nullable = true)
```

When I read this file in pandas the schema changes for decimal and is represented as object

```
    pandas_dataframe.dtypes
    TYPE    object
    ID      int32
    SRNO    int32
    AMT     object
```

When I try to get data from the pandas dataframe I get the below Error

```
    ps.sqldf("select * from pandas_dataframe")
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",line 1229, in _execute_context
>      cursor, statement, parameters, context
>    File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 577, in do_executemany
>      cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
>   sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.

Can someone please let me know how to handle such a scenario where I need to select a decimal field in pandas dataframe.

Comment: the first table looks like a pyspark dataframe? 2nd your missing a connection argument in your sql call, `pd.read_sql(your_query,connection_string)`

Comment: @Datanovice Yes, The first table is from spark and I just used that to show the schema and data in my parquet file.
I am using sqldf of pandasql  and not read_sql. This is running directly on the pandas dataframe and does not need a connection string.